# Why am I getting syntax error for the following sql in sybase?

Tags: t-sql, syntax-error, sybase, sqlanywhere

I get an syntax error on line 7 - "BEGIN" for while -

```
 BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table1)
        THEN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table2)
            THEN
            WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table3)
            BEGIN
                BEGIN TRANSACTION;

                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            END
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END
```

Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: Have you tried using T-SQL `IF`, instead of Watcom `IF - THEN` syntax?  http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/if-tsql-statement.html

Comment: @MichaelGardner It did work, but unfortunately not yet working in the bigger picture. I'm guessing if we use both syntaxes mixed I guess it may cause issues?

Comment: not sure about whether that causes issues or not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was as @Michael pointed out, there are two different type of dialects - [T-SQL and WATCOM-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945544/sql-anywhere-watcom-sql-or-t-sql), I had to rewrite **while loop** in Watcom-SQL syntax to be compatible with rest of Watcom-sql syntax -

```
BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table1)
        THEN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table2)
            THEN
            WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table3) LOOP
            BEGIN
                BEGIN TRANSACTION;

                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            END LOOP;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END
```